# Graph of a function in the neighbourhood of $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm new in Calculus II. Given the function $f(x)=(x^2(e^x−1))^{\frac{1}{5}}$, I would like to determine a qualitative graph of the function in the neighbourhood of x=0. I know that there might be an inflection point in x=0, but I'm stuck as I don't really know how to proceed. Should I calculate the second derivative in $x=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems designed for using power series expansions (i.e. Taylor series), which is usually covered towards the end of U.S. calculus 2 courses, but since you didn't say what *your* Calculus II consists of (or even say what you've covered so far), I'm going to take the power series approach.

In what follows I'll show that

$$ x^{2/5}(e^x - 1)^{1/5} \;\; = \;\; x^{3/5} \; + \; \frac{1}{10}x^{8/5} \; + \; \frac{1}{75}x^{13/5} \; + \; \cdots $$

I’ll avoid taking derivatives by using basic algebraic manipulation along with the expansions of $e^u$ and $(1+u)^{1/5}:$

$$e^u \;\; = \;\; 1 \; + \; u \; + \; \frac{1}{2}u^2 \; + \; \frac{1}{6}u^3 \; + \; \frac{1}{24}u^4 \; + \; \cdots $$

$$ (1+u)^{1/5} \;\; = \;\; 1 \; + \; \frac{1}{5}u \; - \; \frac{2}{25}u^2 \; + \; \frac{6}{125}u^3 \; - \; \cdots    $$

The expansion for $(1+u)^{1/5}$ is the binomial expansion for the exponent $\frac{1}{5}.$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1971690/13130), using $t=\frac{1}{5}.$

In what follows I’ll carry out the computations far enough to obtain the first three terms of the expansion.

$$ x^{2/5}(e^x - 1)^{1/5} \;\; = \;\; x^{2/5}\cdot \left[ \left( 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{6}x^3 + \cdots \right) \; - \; 1 \right]^{1/5}  $$

$$ = \;\; x^{2/5}\cdot \left[x \; + \; \frac{1}{2}x^2 \; + \; \frac{1}{6}x^3 \; + \; \cdots \right]^{1/5} $$

$$ = \;\; x^{2/5}\cdot \left[ x\left(1 \; + \; \frac{1}{2}x \; + \; \frac{1}{6}x^2 \; + \; \cdots \right)\right]^{1/5} $$

$$ = \;\; x^{2/5}\cdot x^{1/5} \cdot \left[1 \; + \; \frac{1}{2}x \; + \; \frac{1}{6}x^2 \; + \; \cdots \right]^{1/5} $$

$$ = \;\; x^{3/5}\cdot \left[1 \; + \; \left(\frac{1}{2}x \; + \; \frac{1}{6}x^2 \; + \; \cdots\right) \right]^{1/5} $$

$$ = \;\; x^{3/5}\cdot \left[1 \; + \; u \right]^{1/5}, $$

where $u \; = \; \left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{6}x^2 + \cdots \right).$

Thus, we have

$$ x^{2/5}(e^x - 1)^{1/5} \;\; = \;\; x^{3/5}\cdot \left[1 \; + \; u \right]^{1/5} $$

$$= \;\; x^{3/5} \cdot \left[ 1 \; + \; \frac{1}{5}u \; - \; \frac{2}{25}u^2 \; + \; \frac{6}{125}u^3 \; - \; \cdots  \right] $$

$$= \;\; x^{3/5} \cdot \left[ 1  +  \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{6}x^2 + \cdots \right) - \frac{2}{25}\left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{6}x^2 + \cdots \right)^2 + \frac{6}{125}\left(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{6}x^2 + \cdots \right)^3 - \cdots  \right] $$

$$= \;\; x^{3/5} \cdot \left[ 1  +  \frac{1}{5}x\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}x + \cdots \right) - \frac{2}{25}x^2\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}x + \cdots \right)^2 + \frac{6}{125}x^3\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}x + \cdots \right)^3 - \cdots  \right] $$

To obtain the correct first three terms, we need to obtain the correct first three terms inside the square brackets (i.e. up through quadratic in $x).$ In everything that follows, I'll use $\;+ \; \cdots \;$ at the point where we do not need to continue any further, given that all we want are the correct terms up through quadratic in $x.$

$$ \frac{1}{5}x\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}x + \cdots \right) \;\; = \;\; 0 \; + \;\frac{1}{10}x \; + \; \frac{1}{30}x^2 \; + \; \cdots $$

$$ \frac{2}{25}x^2\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}x + \cdots \right)^2 \;\; = \;\; \frac{2}{25}x^2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \; + \; \cdots \;\; = \;\; 0 \; + \; 0x \; + \; \frac{1}{50}x^2 \; + \; \cdots $$

$$  \frac{6}{125}x^3\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}x + \cdots \right)^3 \;\; = \;\; 0 \;+ \; 0x \; + \; 0x^2 \; + \; \cdots $$

Using these, we get

$$= \;\; x^{3/5} \cdot \left[ 1  +  \left(0 + \frac{1}{10}x + \frac{1}{30}x^2 + \cdots\right) - \left(0 + 0x + \frac{1}{50}x^2 + \cdots\right) + \left(0 + 0x + 0x^2 + \cdots\right) - \cdots  \right] $$

$$= \;\; x^{3/5} \cdot \left[ 1 \; + \; \frac{1}{10}x \; + \; \frac{1}{30}x^2 \; - \; \frac{1}{50}x^2 \; + \; \cdots  \right] $$

$$= \;\; x^{3/5} \cdot \left[ 1 \; + \; \frac{1}{10}x \; + \; \frac{1}{75}x^2 \; + \; \cdots  \right] $$

$$ = \;\; x^{3/5} \; + \; \frac{1}{10}x^{8/5} \; + \; \frac{1}{75}x^{13/5} \; + \; \cdots $$

The expansion above agrees with what [WolframAlpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+(x%5E(2%2F5))*((e%5Ex)+-+1)%5E(1%2F5)).

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E(2%2F5))*((e%5Ex)+-+1)%5E(1%2F5),+x%5E(3%2F5)+between+0+and+4) for a graph of $y = x^{2/5}(e^x - 1)^{1/5}$ and $y = x^{3/5}$ for $0 < x < 4$ on the same axes.

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E(2%2F5))*((e%5Ex)+-+1)%5E(1%2F5),+x%5E(3%2F5)+%2B+(1%2F10)*x%5E(8%2F5)+between+0+and+4) for a graph of $y = x^{2/5}(e^x - 1)^{1/5}$ and $y = x^{3/5} + \frac{1}{10}x^{8/5}$ for $0 < x < 4$ on the same axes.

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E(2%2F5))*((e%5Ex)+-+1)%5E(1%2F5),+x%5E(3%2F5)+%2B+(1%2F10)*x%5E(8%2F5)+%2B+(1%2F75)*x%5E(13%2F5)+between+0+and+4) for a graph of $y = x^{2/5}(e^x - 1)^{1/5}$ and $y = x^{3/5} + \frac{1}{10}x^{8/5} + \frac{1}{75}x^{13/5}$ for $0 < x < 4$ on the same axes.