# Understanding binomial theorem with negative integer of n

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs, negative-binomial

I’m a student studying mathematics and I understood how the binomial theorem with positive integer of *n* works.

But I couldn’t really understand the progress of how the binomial theorem with negative power works.
By searching internet, I found the formula of binomial theorem with negative integer of $n$ but I can’t understand how it came across.
(Also, why does it doesn’t start with $(a+b)$ nor $(x+y)$, but $(1+x)$?)

I’m not sure how it can be progressed from the binomial theorem with positive integer.
I’ve seen some proves using combinatorial methods, but I also couldn’t understand.

Help me to understand how binomial theorem with negative power can be drawn.
​

Comment: Binomial requires 2 ("bi") values. To iterate a positive integer you must include an integer which simplifies to 1. Thus with $1+n$ the constant $1$ is bound to $n$. So we can conclude that for any set of $n$, $1+n$ exists as a subset. We can then say for all $x$ in the Universe $N$, $x|x +1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the binomial theorem to calculate binomials with a negative exponent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971660/how-to-use-the-binomial-theorem-to-calculate-binomials-with-a-negative-exponent) - for negative $m$ we have $$
(a+b)^m = a^m \left( 1 + \frac b a \right)^m = a^m \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom m k \left(\frac b a \right)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom m k a^{m-k} b^k.
$$